# SQL Server 2012 Reset sum when value is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
Col 1   Value 
--------------
val1    5
val2    45
val3    6
val4    NULL
val5    NULL
val6    65
val7    25
val8    NULL
val9    545
val10   NULL
val11   NULL
val12   NULL
```

I have this table and I must sum the values from column `Value`, but when `Value` is null, I must reset the sum and start from 0. So the first sum must be 56 then 90 then 545. How can I do that? Thanks

The expected result is a table with 3 rows with following values 56,90,545

Comment: can u include expected out put in a snip pls

Comment: how do you want receive the value? the aggregate SUM return an unique value(the sum of rows), you need three values?

Comment: I need the agregate sum.The expected result is a table with 3 rows that have values 56,90,545

Comment: @AlexC. Do your table has a Id column? [Col 1] column is dummy data or your real data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query. It will create group base on NULL on value column.

**Updated:** If your [Col 1] is dummy data and there are no columns for us to sort the data. This query can not guarantee.

```
declare @temp table(col1 varchar(50), value int)

insert into @temp values('val1',5)
insert into @temp values('val2',45)
insert into @temp values('val3',6)
insert into @temp values('val4',null)
insert into @temp values('val5',null)
insert into @temp values('val6',65)
insert into @temp values('val7',25)
insert into @temp values('val8',null)
insert into @temp values('val9',545)
insert into @temp values('val10',null)
insert into @temp values('val11',null)
insert into @temp values('val12',null)

select value, 0 as groupNo
into #temp 
from @temp

declare @group int = 1

update t
set @group = case when value is not null then @group else @group + 1 end
    ,groupNo = @group
from #temp as t

select sum(value) as SumValue
from #temp
where value is not null
group by groupNo
drop table #temp
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I agreed with you, if there are no thing we can do a sort, this one can not guarantee the result

Answer (score 2):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/MIBF3005)**

```
with cte as (
    SELECT *,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN [Value] IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
               OVER (order by [Col 1]) as grp
    FROM Table1       
) 
SELECT SUM(value)
FROM cte
GROUP BY grp
HAVING SUM(value) IS NOT NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

NOTE: I have to fix your data so can order using the value of `[Col 1]`. `1` to `01`. Otherwise you need provide a field to order the data because data set doesn't have an intrinsic order.

Comment: You are cheating a bit: `val1` not `val01` :)

Comment: @lad2025 Sue me?

Comment: @lad2025 Ohh I see, i just tought was a typing, let me explain that.

Comment: I tested, it returns 5,51,90, and 545. Are you test it ?

Comment: @EdwardN yes, there is a link to the demo solution. But as I just add the explanation on the answer I have to change the data a bit so can order by `[Col 1]`

Comment: @MichaelEdmison Your comment seem incomplete?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I think that the value of [Col 1] is dummy data, he want to group base on the NULL break value

Comment: keep hitting Enter instead of Shift Enter for new line.
Difference between Comment vs Answer Section. Sorry

Comment: @EdwardN You need something to order the data, otherwise you cant group by null.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza can you check out my answer? If we not consider about performance issue with temporary table, are there any problem with that solution?

Comment: @EdwardN yes that can work. performance probably the same, because you need do a `FULL TABLE SCAN` anyway. But dont know how much time take the sort .

Answer (score 2):

As a alternative with @Juan Carlos Oropeza option, you can do this.

Keeping the Column Name the same with the VAL1, VAL2 etc...
Replace:

```
 OVER (order by [Col 1]) as grp
```

WITH:

```
OVER (order by CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING([Col 1],4,10))) as grp
```